# Different ascending values depending on other attribute in table in select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view

I want the following table (it's from a join if thats relevant)

```
 id  | atr | order (actually date and time)
----------------
  3  | foo  | 4
  6  | foo  | 3
  2  | bar  | 1
  9  | bar  | 2
```

to become this

```
 id  | atr  | order | suborder
-------------------------------
  6  | foo  |   3   |   1
  3  | foo  |   4   |   2
  2  | bar  |   1   |   1
  9  | bar  |   2   |   2
```

with a SELECT for a VIEW.

The closest I've gotten is 1,2,3,4 in the suborder column using rownum. But I haven't figured out anything to separate the "indices" by another attribute.

How could this be done?

Comment: What does your SQL look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use windowed function [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm):

```
SELECT id,atr ,"order",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY atr ORDER BY "order") AS suborder
FROM table_name;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404476)**</kbd>

`order` is keyword and you need to quote it.

Comment: Thank you lad! This solved my problem, now to learn what I just did. Btw I didn't think about it being a keyword, next time I'll use better naming in questions here. None of those column names where the same as in my sql anyway. Thanks again!